# Sync Product Downloads with Downloadable Product Permissions in Woocommerce orders

Tags: woocommerce

I have a simple Product set to Virtual and downloadable:
Virtual as users buy access to a webinar
Downloadable as users get access to files and a video of the webinar

My problem is, I want users to always see the current available files under the “Downloads” Section of My Account

Is there a way to sync the product downloads so any user who purchased that product will also see the latest list of downloads under the account page?

At the moment, I need to go into each order and:

- Revoke access to all downloads
- Grant Access again to the product download